# Populate days and dates of selected month and year from two respective dropdowns

Tags: javascript, php

I need to display days of selected month and date on press of *Go* button.

I have tried `REQUEST` and `GET` to get it from URL, `onchange()` but I am  definitely doing something wrong. I know that the current code is static and displays values of only 9th month of 2003.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <form id="frmA" class="form-inline" role="form" >
        <td align="right">
            <select id="month" name="month" class="form-control" required="required">
                <option value="">Select Month...</option>
                <option value='1'>January</option>
                <option value='2'>February</option>
                <option value='3'>March</option>
                <option value='4'>April</option>
                <option value='5'>May</option>
                <option value='6'>June</option>
                <option value='7'>July</option>
                <option value='8'>August</option>
                <option value='9'>September</option>
                <option value='10'>October</option>
                <option value='11'>November</option>
                <option value='12'>December</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>  
            <select id="year" name="year" class="form-control" required="required">
            <?php 
                foreach (range(date('Y'), $earliest_year) as $x) {
                print '<option value="'.$x.'"'.($x === $already_selected_value ? ' 
                selected="selected"' : '').'>'.$x.'</option>';}
                ?>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Go!" />
        </td>
    </form>
</tr>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            $date = '2003-09-01';
            $end = '2003-09-' . date('t', strtotime($date)); 
            i=1;
            while(strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end) && $i <= strtotime($end))  {
                $day_num = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($date));
                $day_name = date('l', strtotime($date));
                $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
                echo "<tr><td>$day_num - $day_name</td></tr>";
                i++;
            }
            ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you lack a few things in your code : 1/ a method + an action in 'form' 2/ assign $vars before using them on line -> $date = '2003-09-01'; check this sample of code with minors corrections [LINK](https://pastebin.com/u0ty2g45) EDIT: not a good thing to put form within TR/TD imho

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I have just started learning php and will keep your advice in mind(form within tr/td). Thanks again (Y)

Comment: glad it helped, if so, please accept answer ;)

Comment: Your html markup is invalid, A form is not allowed to be a child element of a table, tbody or tr. Attempting to put one there will tend to cause the browser to move the form to it appears after the table (while leaving its contents — table rows, table cells, inputs, etc — behind).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you lack a few things in your code : 1/ a method + an action in 'form' 2/ assign $vars before using them on line -> $date = '2003-09-01';

```
 <table>
<tbody>
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$month = $_POST['month'];
$year = $_POST['year'];

$date = "$year-$month-01";
$end = "$year-$month-" . date('t', strtotime($date)); 

echo"[ $month / $year / $date / $end ]";
/* code below will throw an error 
$i=1;
while( (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end)) && ($i <= strtotime($end))      )  {
$day_num = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($date));
$day_name = date('l', strtotime($date));
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
echo "<tr><td>$day_num - $day_name</td></tr>";
i++;
}
*/
?>
</tbody>
</table>

<table>
<tr>
<form id="frmA" class="form-inline" role="form" method="post" action="mypage.php" >
<td align="right">

<select id="month" name="month" class="form-control" required="required">
                    <option value="">Select Month...</option>
                    <option value='1'>January</option>
                    <option value='2'>February</option>
                    <option value='3'>March</option>
                    <option value='4'>April</option>
                    <option value='5'>May</option>
                    <option value='6'>June</option>
                    <option value='7'>July</option>
                    <option value='8'>August</option>
                    <option value='9'>September</option>
                    <option value='10'>October</option>
                    <option value='11'>November</option>
                    <option value='12'>December</option>
  </select>
</td>

<td>  
<select id="year" name="year" class="form-control" required="required">
<?php
foreach (range(date('Y'), $earliest_year) as $x) {
print '<option value="'.$x.'"'.($x === $already_selected_value ? ' 
selected="selected"' : '').'>'.$x.'</option>';}
?>
</select>
</td>

<td>
<input type="submit" value="Go!" />
</td>
</form>
</tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: A form is not allowed to be a child element of a table, tbody or tr. Attempting to put one there will tend to cause the browser to move the form to it appears after the table (while leaving its contents — table rows, table cells, inputs, etc — behind).

Comment: *you lack a few things in your code : 1/ a method* False a form always have a method even if you don't write one

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile: but it's more clean of a code to put one, wouldn't you say ? and +1 as we both mentionned the form/html :)

Comment: `<form></form>` and `<form method="GET"></form>` same thing

Comment: Thanks..your advice is appreciated..It got the code running clean..thanks again :)

Comment: @ManishChaudhary : can you please update the code including the portion I did not debug ? Just to help any further folks who'll ask

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<tbody>
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$month = $_REQUEST['month'];
$year = $_REQUEST['year'];

$date = "$year-$month-01";
$end = "$year-$month-" . date('t', strtotime($date)); 

$i=1;
while( (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end)) && ($i <= strtotime($end))  )  {
$day_num = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($date));
$day_name = date('l', strtotime($date));
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
echo "<tr><td>$day_num - $day_name</td></tr>";
$i++; 
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
<form id="frmA" class="form-inline" role="form" method="post" action="mypage.php" >
<table>
<tr>
<td align="right">

<select id="month" name="month" class="form-control" required="required">
                    <option value="">Select Month...</option>
                    <option value='1'>January</option>
                    <option value='2'>February</option>
                    <option value='3'>March</option>
                    <option value='4'>April</option>
                    <option value='5'>May</option>
                    <option value='6'>June</option>
                    <option value='7'>July</option>
                    <option value='8'>August</option>
                    <option value='9'>September</option>
                    <option value='10'>October</option>
                    <option value='11'>November</option>
                    <option value='12'>December</option>
</select>
</td>

<td>  
<select id="year" name="year" class="form-control" required="required">
<?php
foreach (range(date('Y'), $earliest_year) as $x) {
print '<option value="'.$x.'"'.($x === $already_selected_value ?'selected="selected"' : '').'>'.$x.'</option>';}
?>
</select>
</td>

<td>
<input type="submit" value="Go!" />
</td>

</tr>
</table>
</form>
```